# Quick and easy way to generate a tarball from a bazaar checkout

Tags: tar, bazaar

I need to generate a tarball from a project checked out from a bazaar repository. Since I'm not a regular bazaar user, can anyone tell me if there is such a command and its syntax?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Maybe it's appropriate for superuser.stackechange.com.

Comment: Well, it is about a tool closely related to programming (a DCVS), so most probably people here will be able to answer it

Comment: I understand, I'm just trying to save you a downvote or two! :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks Codie. But my experience using both SU and SO shows that usually people on SU are not very used to specific programming tools like 'bazaar', 'git' and such, so the chance of getting a quick answer here is greater. We can flag it so the mods can migrate it there if it is too much off-topic.

Comment: I guess it should be ok to leave it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119250/where-is-the-line-between-programming-specific-tools-and-programming

Comment: Yeah, not sure tar is as directly related to programming as git, but I at least acknowledge that it's a gray area, and also that you haven't gotten the downvotes I thought you would.  Hope you get the answer you need.

Comment: Maybe it's safe to say that stuff there is a proper tag for is good to stay here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
bzr export /path/to/myproj.tar.gz
```

Bazaar will automatically recognize the format by the suffix, but you can also use the `--format` option to specify the format explicitly. Files within the archive will be in the directory `myproj` (i.e., derived from the filename). You can override that with the `--root` option. See `bzr export --help` for more options.

Comment: Great! I was a little lost in all the help options and couldn't find any "package" string while grepping it.